# Running a python scripts and catching argument into another python script

Tags: python

I am unable to get this working .
I have something like this

```
python executor.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Ant then I have another python script which is not directly called by excecutor.py but by some another script file which is being called in executor.py .Lets it call

```
script.py
```

there is a variable name `argument` in which i want to catch `arg1`.
How to do do it  ?

Comment: Would you run script.py inside executor.py ? [*subprocess*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: @kcorlidy no , it is not directly being executed in executor.py , There are many functions inside script.py which are being called in executor.py at multiple places . I just want to catch the arg1 in my script.py , then everything will fall in place .

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are doing `import script` within the `executor.py` script. If this is the case you have to add to `executor.py`:

```
import script
import sys
argument_1 = sys.argv[1] # since [0] is the script name
...
script.yourfunction(argument_1)
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming script.py and executor.py are in the same folder:

script.py:

```
def function1(somearg, otherarg):
    pass
def function2(moreargs):
    pass
```

and executor.py

```
import sys
import script

# assign input args; check for valid arguments etc..
arg1 = sys.argv[1]
arg2 = sys.argv[2]
etc...

# call system functions
script.function1(arg1, arg2)
script.function2(arg1)
```